# Linebreak/Textwrap in p:messages

Tags: primefaces

I have a p:messages Element in a Dialog. When the Message added by a Validator in this Element is too long, the Dialog gets wider, but stays in the same Position, which looks weird. Is there a way to get the Message to fit the dialog instead of the dialog changing size to fit the message?

The xhtml:

```
<p:dialog header="Benutzer erstellen / verwalten" id="userManageDialog"
      widgetVar="userManageDialog"
      modal="true"
      showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
<p:outputPanel id="userData" rendered="#{not empty userDetailController.user}">
    <!-- this is needed to be able to display validation messages from controller -->

    <p:messages id="messages" closable="true">
        <p:autoUpdate/>
    </p:messages>

    <div class="ui-fluid p-grid">
        <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-12">
            <p:outputLabel id="passwordLabel" for="password" value="Passwort: "/>
            <p:password id="password" value="#{userDetailController.user.password}"
                        disabled="#{not userDetailController.newUser}" redisplay="true"
                        required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Bitte geben Sie ein Passwort ein."/>
        </div>
    </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

</p:dialog>

The Validator:

```
    public boolean isValid(String password) {
    boolean valid = true;
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        validationMsgs.add("Passwort ist leer!");
        valid = false;
    }
    Matcher m = p.matcher(password);
    if(!m.matches()) {
        validationMsgs.add("Das Passwort muss zwischen 6 und 20 Zeichen lang sein und mindestens einen Buchstaben und eine Zahl enthalten!");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: You should try with some css, like width (`width="300"`) or max-width (`style="max-width: 300px"`) of the dialog. Or you can do the same thing to his children (one of the div).

Comment: You can also do `escape="false"` in your p:messages and add `<br/>` tags in your actual messages where you want them to break.